# Is there a way to disable copy elision in c++ compiler

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor

In c++98, the following program is expected to call the copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
  public:
    A() { cout << "default" ; }

    A(int i) { cout << "int" ; }


    A(const A& a) { cout << "copy"; }
};

int main ()
{
   A a1;
   A a2(0);
   A a3 = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

That is evident if you declare the copy constructor explicit in above case (the compiler errors out). But I don't I see the output of copy constructor when it is not declared as explicit. I guess that is because of copy elision. Is there any way to disable copy elision or does the standard mandates it?

Comment: Where should the copy constructor be called?

Comment: I see no usage of copy construction in the `main` function.

Comment: `gcc` have `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable copy elision

Comment: Clang has this flag too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pre `C++ 17`

```
A a3 = 0;
```

will [call](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XjGSRLUOznr3EWvR) copy constructor unless copy is elided. Pass `-fno-elide-constructors` flag

from `C++17`, copy elision is guaranteed. So you will [not see](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uUHtwLzV0ST7aBVv) copy constructor getting called.

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression this would never call a copy constructor, even in `c++11/14`.

Comment: No, `A a3 = 0;` [will not](https://wandbox.org/permlink/C8nX13eFdaSmPHAv) call a copy constructor in pre-C++17 standards on GCC. The reason it does is because you included the flag in your compilation string.

Comment: @Ron I thought so too, but what about [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4wQT166R2jVFw4pb)?

Comment: @Ron What if `A a3 = 0;` is `A a3 = A(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong understanding what the copy elision is. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) for more info.

In this particular case, if you define the constructor explicit, it will cause an error because   `A a3 = 0;` on this line the compiler created a object using 0.

Comment: constructor being `explicit` has nothing to do with copy elision.

Comment: I agree his understanding is wrong (via comments), but he has got the answer correct.